# J2ME: How to press keypad programmatically?

Tags: java, java-me, mobile

Is it possible to press keypad programmatically so that number for the key pressed shows on the screen? See the screenshot below for more explanation please:

[image]

**Details:**
Nokia N70
CLDC 1.1
MIDP 2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How you approach it will depend on what you want to achieve.

You can quite easily simulate pressing keys on a `Canvas`, by calling your Canvas's `keyPressed()`, `keyReleased()` and `keyRepeated()` methods directly.

This could be good for testing a canvas-based game, ensuring a given state is entered when certain keys are pressed on the canvas.

However, this won't allow you to control any form-based interaction, or native prompts.  So you can't start the MIDlet, navigate through a LCDUI `Form` or `List`, accept a native security prompt, or edit a native `TextBox`.  You'd need to use an emulator and some form of test scripting framework which simulates keypresses, such as [Eggplant](http://www.testplant.com/).

Comment: @funkybro: could not really get the point to my answer, do you mean it is not possible to type (like when we call) on the screen programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to mimicking the keypressed process, just call the keypressed with the int of key as argument, for example keyPressed(-8);

Or are you trying to display the key number in the screen ?